# Jupyter notebook is extremely slow suddenly after merging two python pandas dataframe.It is happening on both my mac and window

Tags: python, performance, datetime, merge, jupyter-notebook

I am working on my first data project for portfolio and I am trying to merge two pandas dataframes on datetime object. After merging two dataframes my jupyter notebook became extremely slow and took forever to re-run each cell. I am using git and github and It seems these are bit getting slow too. 
I think I wrote the code in very inefficient way and this is my first project to apply internship and now I am so sad.. Please help....

https://github.com/Happydogs/Aurora_Policing_Project/blob/master/Aurora_Policing_Project.ipynb

I do have my code on github

Merging datasets

```
data.head()
data['date'] = pd.to_datetime(data['date'])
weather.head()
weather['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(weather['DATE'])
weather['DATE'].head()
police_weather_data = pd.merge(left = data, right = weather, left_on = 
'date', right_on = 'DATE', how = 'left')
police_weather_data.head()
```

I think I did something wrong. It is actually running, but after running the code, jupyter notebook is ridiculously and extremely slow.

Comment: how big are the datasets?

Comment: data.shape is (163964 ,7) and weather.shape is (1826, 2) before merging dataframe 'data' is running pretty fast.